# Is there a documentation on how to use weather overlay from noaa.gov?

Tags: maps, overlay, weather

I am trying to add a weather overlay to my maps , the tile images on Noaa.gov are what i want but i couldn't find any documentation on how to construct url to consume & arrange tiles of overlays for a given lon/lat. below is the a sample url that returns a single tile.

http://radarcache.srh.noaa.gov/tc/tc.py/1.0.0/ridge::NAT-N0Q-201211191510/8/62/97.png

**update:**
The web service i am working on generates a sectional aviation chart/map for a given lon/lat dimension and zoom level . one of the overlays i am rendering on top of the generated base map is weather(radar reflective ..) 
  based on the information i have (lon/lat, dimension and zoom level) i want to render weather overlay on top of my base map.
  the challenge i am facing is how do i get weather overlay using lon/lat ?

Comment: What kinds of data layers can you import?  .shp, mid/mif, .kml, .tab?

Comment: currently none: i was planing to get transparent png and render it on top of my base map. but if that is not possible i can start looking at .shp format. if i were to import shp format can i get the weather information from NOAA API ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After researching a lot i found out that NOAA Tile System uses [this](http://www.maptiler.org/google-maps-coordinates-tile-bounds-projection/) Tile arrangement, based on that i was able to get PNG images overlay for a given (lon/lat/zoom)  as follows

http://ridgewms.srh.noaa.gov/tc/tc.py/1.0.0/ridge::NAT-N0Q-{0:yyyyMMddHHmm}/{1}/{2}/{3}.png

Where

- {0:yyyyMMddHHmm} = date time in 5 minute increments
- {1} ZoomLevel
- {2} X or tile column
- {3} Y or Tile Row

Comment: http://ridgewms.srh.noaa.gov/tc/tc.py/1.0.0/N0Q_0/{z}/{x}/{y}.png if you don't want to have to put the date in there.

Comment: I'm looking for a tile api for the same purpose :) Is this API still supposed to be available? The requests seems to time out

Comment: @Jan  looks like the N0Q_0 layer no longer exists but there seems to be other layers available   http://ridgewms.srh.noaa.gov/tc/tc.py/1.0.0/usa_pcpn24/1/0/0.png  this link uses usa_pcpn24  other options are usa_pcpn12
 * usa_pcpn168
 * usa_pcpn3
 * usa_pcpn1

Comment: cheers, are those layers ids and meaning documented somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Without more information about what you are trying to integrate into, here is what I know.  If you want to create a custom KML file, there is [this page](http://wdssii.nssl.noaa.gov/?r=products) that will do that for you.  For more info about other layers, check out [this page](http://nowcoast.noaa.gov/help/mapservices.shtml?name=mapservices) as well.

If you provide more info about your environment, we might be able to help with more specifics.

EDIT:

For just the transparent gifs, see this page here  http://forecast.weather.gov/jetstream/doppler/ridge_download.htm

There is quite a bit of information for downloading actual data here http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/oa/radar/radardata.html

Comment: I've tried that but in order to use that interface one has to know the "xxx - Radar site ID"  i only have lat/lon.